# Multiply Value From Multiple Tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I'm using mySql 5.1. I got in a trouble. The query below is working perfect. I want to **replace the constant value 100 with value from database with respect to corresponding SID.** But I don't know how to do it.

```
INSERT INTO ResultTable(SID,Date,Result) 
    SELECT SID,DATE(`Time`),(MAX(SValue)-MIN(SValue))* 100 
      FROM table1   
  GROUP BY Date(`Time`),SID;


            Table 1
------------------------------------------
SID         Time                SValue
------------------------------------------
7       2013-05-06 12:06:17     5668
8       2013-04-10 16:17:49     11434.9
8       2013-04-10 16:18:54     11435.5
7       2013-04-10 16:21:04     11436.8
7       2013-04-10 16:22:09     11437.4
8       2013-04-10 16:25:24     11439.2


    Table2
---------------------
SID     EValue
---------------------
7            10
8            100


        Result Table
------------------------------------------
SID     Date                Result
------------------------------------------
7       2013-05-06               56680
8       2013-04-10               1143490
8       2013-04-10               1143550
7       2013-04-10               114368
7       2013-04-10               114374
8       2013-04-10               1143920
```

Existing query :

```
    SELECT SID,DATE(`Time`),(MAX(SValue)-MIN(SValue))* 100 
      FROM table1   
  GROUP BY Date(`Time`),SID;
```

My Query :

```
      select (h1.EValue * ss.SValue) AS Emission 
        from Table2 h1 
  inner join (
       select SID, (MAX(SValue)-MIN(SValue)) AS SValue 
         from Table1 
     group by Date(`Time`), SID
      ) ss on h1.SID = ss.SID
```

But my query gives some extra values. My questions are

1. What I'm doing wrong here?
2. Why extra values coming?
3. Is there any better way to do this?

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: In your example, the results don't seem to match your query.  The `Date(`Time`)` function would remove the times from the dates.  In your results the dates have times.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for your quick response. That was a mistake from me. I have updated the question

Comment: Your sample results still don't match the original query that you gave.  This is what is making things confusing.  In the original query you gave, you would only get one value for each Date/SID combo (because of your `GROUP BY` clause).  In your results you have multiple results for the same Date/SID.  If these matched, it would be easier to know what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  I simply join to table2 and get the EValue from there and replaced the 100.

```
SELECT  h1.SID, DATE(`Tm`), 
        (MAX(SValue)-MIN(SValue))* ss.EValue 

FROM    table1 as h1

        JOIN table2 as ss
        ON h1.SID = ss.SID

GROUP BY Date(`Tm`), h1.SID;
```

I think the reason you were getting "extra" values was because you were grouping by date and SID in your sub-query, but you weren't showing the date in your main query.  So you would have multiple results for SIDs that had different dates.

Comment: Your code returns exactly what my code giving. Actually it makes some data loss from the actual values. In the actual table, there is 158 rows and after executing the query, it gets reduced to 107, almost 51 rows lost.

Comment: It is grouping by SID and date.  I am guessing rows are not being lost but are being grouped together.  If you have any SIDs with the same date, you will have less results than input rows.  If this is not what you are looking for you should probably update your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Do this return the expected result (I type without testing -- so it could be some typos -- shame on me)?

```
    SELECT T1.SID,DATE(T1.`Time`),(MAX(T1.SValue)-MIN(T1.SValue))* T2.EValue
        FROM table1 AS T1, Table2 AS T2
        WHERE T1.SID = T2.SID
        GROUP BY Date(T1.`Time`),T1.SID;
```